# Drawing program capable of drawing neural network architecture

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

### Problem

Maybe this question is not a perfect fit for the venue.

The following is a neural network architecture that I found on Andrew Ng's deep learning course. Even though it does not seem to be drawn using tikz (or more task-specific module like [PlotNeuralNet](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet)).

I am wondering if there is software (package) that is capable of drawing diagram like this. I guess the most difficult part is attach mathematical symbol (even this diagram could not do this perfectly well).
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this in Excel.

Comment: The question is currently vague. If you want to draw this using TeX, provide some foundational work in the form of a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). If you're interested in any software, then this is not a good fit as we specialise in TeX-related implementations.

Comment: @Werner why Excel? I think Excel is not good for graphs. Instead MS Visio could be a good starting point.

Comment: @manooooh I think Werner was trying to wave his [sarcasm] sign.

Comment: You tag it `tikz-pgf` and it can easily be done with e.g. the matrix library.

Comment: @manooooh: The question is whether there exists a package that can draw this diagram. I would be able to do that in Excel...

Comment: @marmot Could you provide a starting point (say, an example) to draw similar diagram using matrix library?

Comment: @manooooh I have used MS-Visio before for my undergrad thesis, it is indeed capable of drawing complicated diagram. However, it seems that it could not handle mathematical formulas smoothly. Actually, making it work with maths is a nightmare.

Comment: @Werner Not sure how to draw this using Excel.

Comment: @Werner Even easier and more efficient than excel: just save the above as a graphic and include it with `\includegraphics`. And IMHO this is much more helpful than the excel comment...

Comment: @Mr.Robot: It's obviously made in Excel due to the inconsistent arrow start/end points and the variety of font sizes... something that is easy enough to do without thinking in Excel. You can look at the following [point of departure](https://transfernow.net/137or2v2kzbm) I made in Excel (link will expire in 7 days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a *start*. The arrows are drawn automagically and the boxes are done with `shapes.multipart`. The `split row` style is hopefully self-explanatory, and the rest is done very quickly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,every text node part/.style={text
  width=2cm,align=center},split row/.style={nodes={draw,rectangle split,
    rectangle split draw splits=true,rectangle split parts=#1}}]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    row 2/.style={split row=2},
    row 3/.style={split row=4},
    row sep=2em,column sep=2em,
    execute at end matrix={% automatically add vertical arrows
    \foreach \Y [evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(\Y-1)}] in 
        {2,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
    {\foreach \X in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
    {\draw[-stealth] (\tikzmatrixname-\Y-\X) -- (\tikzmatrixname-\Z-\X);}}}
    ] { $y^1$ & $y^2$ \\
      Sigmoid\nodepart{two}Dense & Sigmoid\nodepart{two}Dense\\     
     Dropout\nodepart{two}blabla\nodepart{three}blabla%
    \nodepart{four}\vphantom{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\Huge A}}xyz & 
      Dropout\nodepart{two}blabla\nodepart{three}blabla%
    \nodepart{four}\vphantom{\raisebox{-1.5ex}{\Huge A}}xyz\\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]